# glassfish says port is occupied. but netstat says no process uses port 80

Tags: glassfish, xampp, wamp, netstat

when i started the glassfish 3+ server, it says that it cannot start because port is occupied. but i tried netstat -aon on command prompt. there is no process using port 80. I have the same problem with wamp and xampp. please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: I've read that from netstat you checked the ports status, but have you tried changing the default ports for Glassfish? Just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish runs per default on port 8080 (normal http service) and port 4848 (admin frontend).

You may have to look for these ports to fix the issue.

Comment: even those ports are notoccupied.